# How i can use variables in stylesheet in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create general variable color in stylesheet, I created it as shown below, but it does not work.

```
'use strict';

import {Dimensions} from "react-native";

var React = require('react-native');

var { StyleSheet } = React;

var { PrimaryColor } = "#DDDDDD";

module.exports = StyleSheet.create({

title_post:{
padding: 20,
color: PrimaryColor
},

button_share:{
backgroundColor: PrimaryColor
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is destructuring assignmetn (invalid):

```
var { PrimaryColor } = "#DDDDDD";
```

It is used to extract values from an object:

```
var { a } = { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(a) // 1
```

This is variable declaration and assignment (what you want):

```
var PrimaryColor = "#DDDDDD";
```